# Xarray is very slow

Tags: multiprocessing, dask, python-multithreading, python-xarray, rasterio

Xarray is very slow.

I needed to read 10 geotiff files (each of 10000 by 10000 size) and calculate mean across 10 images

```
import glob
import threading
import numpy as np
import rasterio, xarray, rioxarray
```

```
files = glob.glob("/data/*.tif")
```

```
xda_lists = []
for fi in files:
  xdaObj = rioxarray.open_rasterio(fi,masked=True,chunks= {'band':1,'y':10000, 'x':10000},lock=threading.Lock())
xda_lists.append(xdaObj)
```

```
xdaMerged = xarray.concat(xda_lists,dim="band",join="override")
```

```
xdaMedian = xdaMerged.median(dim='band',skipna=True)
```

```
xdaMedian.rio.to_raster('out.tif',tiled=True,compress="lzw",lock=threading.Lock())
```

However, its very slow. How can I accelerate it ?? The input images were not tiled.

Comment: The first step is always to profile your code. figure out exactly what is the slow part first, then ask a more specific question on how to make that part faster.